# cделать поля required django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Расширил модель User

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    ROLE_CHOICES = [
        ('U', 'User'),
        ('M', 'Moderator'),
        ('A', 'Admin'),
    ]
    role = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ROLE_CHOICES, default='U')
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'username']
```

Есть вот такой url

```
path('v1/auth/email/', csrf_exempt(views.email))
```

Вью

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def email(requests):
    email = requests.POST['email']
    user = User.objects.get_or_create(username=email, email=email)[0]
    confirmation_code = default_token_generator.make_token(user)
    send_mail('Подтверждение регистрации', f'Пожалуйста, сохраните этот код : 
{confirmation_code},'ivan@yandex.ru',
    [email], fail_silently=False)
    return JsonResponse({'email':email})
```

как сделать так что бы поля email и  username были оба required ? По умолчанию только username  required. Можно ли сделать это наследуясь от AbstractUser или надо наследоваться от AbstractBaseUser ? Можно ли задать требования reqiured на уровне сериализатора ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно удобно управлять полями в `ModelSerializer`:

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer


class CustomUserSerializer(ModelSerializer:

    fields = ['email', 'phone_number']
    extra_kwargs = {
        'email': {'required': True},
        'username': {'read_only': True}
    }

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
```